# Determine whether function $f(x,n) ={\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{1+x^{4}}}}\frac{\tan\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}}{2}, n\in N,x \in [0,\frac{\pi}{4}]$ is bounded

Tags: calculus, measure-theory

Be bounded to the function that is integrable on $ [0,\frac{\pi}{4}]$. The only way  I saw is to try to bound $\sqrt{n}\tan\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}$, but I don't think it can be done, so any help wil be useful.

Ps: Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the given range $0\leq \tan \frac  x {\sqrt n} \leq \frac {2x} {\sqrt n}$. Also $1+x^{4} \geq 1$. This gives $0 \leq f(x,n) \leq \frac {\pi}4$.

Proof of the inequality $\tan y \leq 2y$ for $0\leq y \leq \frac{\pi}4$:
Consider $2y-\tan y$. The derivative of this function is $2-\sec ^{2}y=2-\frac 1 {\cos^{2}y}$. In the interval $[0,\frac{\pi}4]$, $\cos y$ varies between $\frac  1 {\sqrt 2}$ and $1$ so $\cos^{2}y \geq \frac  1 2$. Hence the derivative of $2y-\tan y$  is non-negative , so it is an increasing function . Since its value at $0$ is $0$ it follows that $2y-\tan y \geq 0$.

Comment: Sir, can you explain me more, why is $\tan \frac  x {\sqrt n} \leq \frac  {2x} {\sqrt n}$.

Comment: @user700999 Sorry, I was too busy and I posted  cryptic answer. I have added some details now.